# Does IronPython support C# dynamic type?

Tags: c#, dynamic, ironpython

I have a C# code that I would like to convert to IronPython. One part of the code uses `dynamic` type to construct an object similar to the following construct:

```
dynamic user32 = new DynamicDllImport("user.dll", callingConvention: CallingConvention.Winapi);
user32.MessageBox(0, "Hello World", "Platform Invoke Sample", 0);
```

Is it possible to make IronPython aware of the `user32`'s type (it being dynamic) at runtime and how would I properly invoke a method on it?

Thank you.